# how to change .svg icon or image color when user click on it. in expo react naive

Tags: typescript, react-native, svg, expo

I am new to react native expo. I have two svg images. one is grey color and other is orange. so I want that when user click on it it turn to orange. so how to do that. please help.
here is my code

```
 <Svg
          // xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          width={17.897}
          height={21}
          viewBox="0 0 17.897 21"
        >
          <Path
            data-name="Path 1824"
            d="M8.949 4.435a6.094 6.094 0 00-2.625 11.6l.191-3.688s-.359-.118-.438-.156a1.766 1.766 0 01-.591-.436l-.04-.059-.121-.173a6.109 6.109 0 01-.477-1.172 1.477 1.477 0 01-.048-.181 4.185 4.185 0 01-.041-.589A2.547 2.547 0 016.9 6.968a2.547 2.547 0 012.134 2.613 2.739 2.739 0 01-1.314 2.6l-.441.161.213 4.1a5.978 5.978 0 003.4-.137l.189-3.655a1.959 1.959 0 01-1.188-.824c-.33-.494.254-4.864.254-4.864h.38v4.1h.373v-4.1h.412v4.1h.375v-4.1h.428v4.1h.376v-4.1h.291s.583 4.371.253 4.864a1.965 1.965 0 01-1.176.822l-.017.006.164 3.144A6.095 6.095 0 008.949 4.435zM8.442 1.6a8.949 8.949 0 00-1.655 17.617v-.69a8.282 8.282 0 011.655-16.26v1.614l2.783-1.941L8.442 0v1.6zm0 17.46L11.225 21v-1.813A8.948 8.948 0 0012.8 2.458V3.2a8.28 8.28 0 01-1.575 15.3v-1.381l-2.783 1.94z"
            fill="#f90"
            fillRule="evenodd"
          />
        </Svg>,
```

Comment: If you are new to React then start with a simpler step; change the color of a regular DOM element; once you master that continue with SVG. And maybe not even use React.. first learn how to do it with regular HTML and JavaScript. All those technologies you add make you learn tricks, not the underlying technology.

Comment: bajao taaaaliiiii

Comment: Geen dank, graag gedaan

Answer (score 0):

Please see the example code below:

```
export default class SVGComponent extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        // default color
        color: "#000",
    };
}

render() {
    const { color } = this.state;
    return (
        <Svg
            // xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            width={17.897}
            height={21}
            viewBox="0 0 17.897 21"
            onPress={() => {
                // change SVG color to orange on user click
                this.setState({
                    color: "#f90",
                });
            }}
        >
            <Path
                data-name="Path 1824"
                d="M8.949 4.435a6.094 6.094 0 00-2.625 11.6l.191-3.688s-.359-.118-.438-.156a1.766 1.766 0 01-.591-.436l-.04-.059-.121-.173a6.109 6.109 0 01-.477-1.172 1.477 1.477 0 01-.048-.181 4.185 4.185 0 01-.041-.589A2.547 2.547 0 016.9 6.968a2.547 2.547 0 012.134 2.613 2.739 2.739 0 01-1.314 2.6l-.441.161.213 4.1a5.978 5.978 0 003.4-.137l.189-3.655a1.959 1.959 0 01-1.188-.824c-.33-.494.254-4.864.254-4.864h.38v4.1h.373v-4.1h.412v4.1h.375v-4.1h.428v4.1h.376v-4.1h.291s.583 4.371.253 4.864a1.965 1.965 0 01-1.176.822l-.017.006.164 3.144A6.095 6.095 0 008.949 4.435zM8.442 1.6a8.949 8.949 0 00-1.655 17.617v-.69a8.282 8.282 0 011.655-16.26v1.614l2.783-1.941L8.442 0v1.6zm0 17.46L11.225 21v-1.813A8.948 8.948 0 0012.8 2.458V3.2a8.28 8.28 0 01-1.575 15.3v-1.381l-2.783 1.94z"
                fill={color}
                fillRule="evenodd"
            />
        </Svg>
    );
}
```

}